# how to log ip addresses, time & date to txt file using php?

Tags: php, html

Im trying to save all my visitors ip address and time to a txt file on my website directory.

it started to work then it just stopped.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents("../tab/t/logger.txt", "$ip", FILE_APPEND);
```

or first it create the logger.txt file and now it doesn't. so i created a logger.txt file and now it won't save the ip's to the file. Also how do i add the time & date?

**ERROR**

[26-Mar-2020 19:56:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(../tab.example.com/t/logger.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/li3259rsjyo6/public_html/tab.example.com/t/UserInfo.php on line 2

Comment: Make sure the webserver userid has permission to write the file.

Comment: but it wrote it before and then i tried to edit the file in a different location-then it didn't work so i put it back in the original location on the script and now it doesn't log.

Comment: The error message says `tab.example.com`, but the code says `tab`. That error message can't be coming from the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing like this.
Second parameter to fopen can be used a+ if you want addition to earlier created file.
w will override file every time.
$your_content can be anything you want to write on file. Array string or anything.

```
$file = fopen("data.txt", "w");
fwrite($file, $your_content);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . PHP_EOL;
$file = fopen("data.txt", "w");
fwrite($file, $your_content);
fclose($file);

Comment: it creates the data.txt file but there's nothing logged

Comment: You need to replace $your_content with $ip.

Comment: should i create the data.txt file in the directory?

Comment: I didnt get you question. You can create it anywhere you want by passing the path in first parameter.

Comment: Ok awesome news it works well-now i have to separate the ip addresses into lines or spaces. their all jumble together. what can i do to create pace for the ip addresses? can i create another php file and INCLUDE it to the landing page? or should i continue to add to the ip logger code?

Comment: For space or anything you want you can always concatenate space with your content. For example fwrite($file, $ip . ' ');

Comment: On second part. Its your choice, having a seprate file wil always keeps your code cleaner or may be creating a function and passing IP to that.

Comment: like this:: session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["IP"])){
 $_SESSION["IP"]=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
 $f=fopen("iplog.txt","a+". '');
 fwrite($f,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
 fclose($f);
}
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");

Comment: $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . PHP_EOL;
$file = fopen("data.txt", "w");
fwrite($file, $ip . ' ');
fclose($file);

Comment: now it only saves one ip at a time. it doesn't save multiple ips . it saves 1 ip not all. what am i doing wrong? @MuhammadUmair

Comment: This code between the brackets works and saves all ips but i can't figure out how to put them into different lines.[[[[ session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["IP"])){
 $_SESSION["IP"]=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
 $f=fopen("iplog.txt","a+");
 fwrite($f,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
 fclose($f);
}
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");]]]]] @MuhammadUmair

Answer (score 0):

@MuhammadUmair I got this to work but i can't figure out how to separate the ip addresses into lines

```
    session_start(); if (!isset($_SESSION["IP"])){ 
    $_SESSION["IP"]=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; $f=fopen("iplog.txt","a+"); 
    fwrite($f,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]); fclose($f); } $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
```

Comment: Just add \n after every line like `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] . '\n'`

Comment: how to i close this question as answered? and vote your answer the best?